# How can I implement a piecewise function in Fortran?

Tags: function, fortran

How can I implement a piecewise function in Fortran? For example the step function:

```
f(x) = 1   x>0
f(x) = 0   x<0
```

Comment: Present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are so many ways of doing this that it isn't obvious that you understand the very basics of Fortran: I'm voting to close as "too broad".  If you can explain what you understand about Fortran functions, if constructs, etc., then perhaps we can tailor an answer to your needs.

Comment: Agreed, too broad. mattiav27, please do a Fortran tutorial on your own. Here basically you just need an 'if' block that returns the answer you want depending on the condition.

Comment: It is really just `if (x>0) f = 1 else f = 0 end if` but you need at least some minimal knowledge of Fortran. Or `merge(1,0,x>0)`. Notice you did not specify anything for `x=0`.

Answer (score 0):

If x and f are arrays, I find the WHERE construct to be quite readable to build the step function.

```
where (x > 0)
    f = 1
else
    f = 0
end where
```